# Use cell X3 in function with lookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula, cell

Hey guys I have a bunch of strings in a column and I am getting the row number of the last string by using the following:

```
=MATCH(REPT("z",255),StaticData!G:G)
```

It gives me a number 256 and it is in cell X3.

I am using a lookup and I would like to specify this number in cell X3:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$C$4:$D$256,2,0),"")
```

Where the 260 is right now I would like to place X3 but it is giving me errors.

So like:

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$C$4:$D$X3,2,0),"")`

Anyone know how I can do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `Offset`:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$C$4:OFFSET($D$1,$X$3-1,0),2,0),"")
```

Comment: hmm it just gives me a blank when it should bring a string back

Comment: So the columns C and D are on another sheet and X3 is on another sheet is this why? EDIT: That was the problem, had to specify the sheets before C,D,and X. Thanks!!

Comment: Offset will still work. Easy enough to fix. Add appropriate sheet qualification

Answer (score 1):

In most cases `INDEX` is preferable to `OFFSET` because `OFFSET` is a volatile function - try this version

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$C$4:INDEX(Sheet1!$D:$D,$X$3),2,0),"")`